# extracting word from matching with CSV data file

Tags: python

```
def fetch_data(document):
    with open('data_file.pickle', 'rb') as fp:
        datafile = pickle.load(fp)

    matched_word = []
    for data in datafile.splitlines():
        job_regex = r'[^a-zA-Z]'+data+r'[^a-zA-Z]'
        regular_expression = re.compile(job_regex, re.IGNORECASE)
        regex_result = re.search(regular_expression, document)
        if regex_result:
            matched_word.append(data)
    return matched_word
```

I want to get the matching data from datafile to document, but it returns blank list.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're wanting to see if the data file and document contain the same word, if they both contain then extract it?

Comment: @JackNicholson Yes if it matched with both file

Comment: when i try with open('data_file.pickle', 'r') it gives the error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Ignore what I said, I didn't notice it was pickle extension. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, I believe you should be using word boundaries, \b, instead:

```
job_regex = r'\b'+data+r'\b'
```

Comment: Now i had check line by line code was correct, actually data_file was not correct it shows as [a-bA-B]abc\t\t[a-bA-B], now it works properly, Now I will try your method may be it will another option

Comment: Ah, glad you got it sorted. Perhaps next time give an extract of the data file and the document. It's difficult to perceive at our end.